# MongoCollection updateMany, bulkWrite or something else?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-collection

I am trying to insert / update many records in a MongoCollection. I have a list of Documents to be updated.

```
List<Document> Documents;
```

The list contains some new records that are to be inserted and others are already existing ones which need to be updated. I was looking at the method

```
updateMany() in MongoCollection class
```

but the description says it updates one record. I am confused as to which method should be used.

[Reference](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#updateMany-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-)

Version : 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in javadoc and updateMany() should update multiple records.
I've investigated source code of Mongo, just in case, and it sets "multi" parameter to **true**, so everything should work ok:

```
public UpdateResult  updateMany(final Bson filter, final Bson update, final UpdateOptions updateOptions) {
    return update(filter, update, updateOptions, true); // that true means "multi" is used
}
```